Twilio Stream with Ambience Sound in Node.js
I am using https://github.com/twilio-labs/call-gpt this code for one of my project.
Everything works well but I am not able to add ambiance sound like office sound that user can hear so AI can process the request.
I have tried with node-audio-mixer and ffmpeg but nothing works for me.
Can anyone help me with that?

Hey , were you able to solve this ?
